# Should I solder multiple wires together, or is there a better way?

Tags: soldering, wire

I need to connect 10 thin single-core wires to each other permanently. They will carry at most 1A at 5V in total (100mA each). Can I just solder them together in a lump with shrink wrap tubing around? Is there a better or more normal/professional way? The wago clips is useful for testing, but looks "temporary" and work-in-progress, so I'd like to remove them.

Sorry I don't know the wire gauges, but you'll get an idea from this picture.

[image]

Comment: Why would you have such long wires in something permanent? What are they connected to? What kind of application is this?

Comment: Hi @ElliotAlderson! It's a little LED grid base for an art project with light-diffusing sculptures. Picture: https://photos.app.goo.gl/9wxAX6i8CqGRJ6F4A
An obvious design mistake was to not connect the individual LED strips, both via power and data. I'm keeping the wires long to make it easier to handle, good idea to make them shorter. I'd be happy to have all my other design mistakes pointed out, as I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: I'd drill holes in the base at the end of each strip and take the wires down through them - then connect them together underneath and run a single pair to the supply.

Comment: @Finbarr Thank you, of course I should have thought of drilling holes. Great idea. How would you connect them underneath? All 10 wires joining in the center with a lump of solder and a supply wire?

Comment: That would work, or you could run two lengths of heavy duty wire either side of the holes as busbars and join each strip to them. The main thing is to make sure the ground wires are all connected together and to the ground of whatever is driving the signal wires as well as possible.

Comment: I want to give a thumbs-up to @Finbarr's advice to use **heavy wire** to connect between the strips. It sounds like you may have a total current of 10A going to the strips, and if you use small wire to carry that current some of the strips may be dimmer. I would suggest something like 12 or 14 gauge solid wire used in long lengths to all of the strips, with the thinner wire from each strip soldered to the heavy wire.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Sorry for my unclear text, I'll fix it. I meant a total of 1A, over all the wires. The 15x10 LEDs are max 60mW each, and they all won't be white at full intensity simultaneously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know Digi-Key and I imagine other distributors sell these Butt splices. These ones cover 12-22 AWG and carry up to 24A. They have 2,3,4,5,or 6 position in this series. Might be an option for you situation.I know 3M has some as well that have a sealant in them. Just not sure if they have the same range and amp rating. https://www.digikey.com/short/jwrttp

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's what I'm already using though (see text and picture), and I'm looking for a more professional-looking solution.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a piece of [stripboard](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=stripboard&t=h_&iax=images&ia=images) to solder the wires to, and some [PCB screw terminal connectors](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=pcb+screw+terminal+connectors&t=h_&iax=images&ia=images) for a neat, disconnectable connection to the power supply.

You might need to drill slightly larger holes for the PCB screw terminal connectors.

If you solder all the wires together in one lump, it will be difficult to remove one if a replacement is needed.

Comment: And please, what would you use for bigger cables (eg. 15 wires of 16AVG from a PC ATX PSU)?

Comment: @JinSnow The same, with appropriately-rated terminals, and preferably with ferrules on the wires that go into the screw terminals.

Comment: Great idea, but it takes a lot of space. Is there a subtler way than soldering them in a fat bundle? (I wonder how the pros like you would do it). What about using a crimp ring connector for each one, and attaching them all with a screw/bolt?

Comment: @JinSnow That's more like another question than asking for clarification of the answer ;)